# What files in Flutter project should I NOT push to a remote repo?

Tags: git, github, flutter, dart

I'm pushing my entire Flutter Project to GitHub. But I wonder if there is any safety precautions I should take before bringing it to the public.

I used `git add .` and pushed it to my remote repo.

Maybe there's some sort of private data that shouldn't be shown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

don't know this exact environment, but a quick google search suggested this:

[Consistent .gitignore for Dart and Flutter projects #13892](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13892)
and this
[github/gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Dart.gitignore)

enjoy! :)

Comment: Thanks!, I'm pretty new to git so I didn't know how to search. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Normally, I use this: http://gitignore.io/.
It seems ok, I could list all of my and teammate environments then adding it to .gitignore.
Last but not least add, commit, push.